# What influences and books do modern Jews read today is it as it is said in the encylopedias? please help

Tags: tanach, talmud-bavli

The sources for Jewish law have changed over the years.... I don't think any law written is the law of God anymore. The original books and teachings have been left behind. The Jewish Encyclopedia, the Judaic Encyclopedia and the Universal Jewish Encyclopedia tell us of the movement and change over time, the oldest being the Jewish Encyclopedia, and give the original outline of law and its original words. The only problem is the scribes of the Pharisees. The Jewish Encyclopedia says that the Judaism of the Old Testament and modern Judaism are very different: it says that after Nebuchadnezzar conquered Judea, 6th century BC, and led Judeans to Babylon, they had challenges to keep to their ways. Scribes of the Pharisees were put in place to write new laws. These 70 elders are mentioned to be wrong and made the law of God void. The scribes of the Pharisees prospered and there verbal Judaism was reconstructed and only written down in 135 BC; and they wrote down their religion into the Talmud which prospered and spread even to the powerful land of Khazar. Hence the two variations of the two groups: Babylon Jews and Khazar Jews; Khazar, who are mixed bloodline, making up around 70%. But the books that are read seem to be from the Old Testament, as, once they came to Europe, the scribes of the Pharisees had to adjust again. I would like to know, though: today, what do people read from? As the Jewish Encyclopedia states no one reads from the Old Testament; the 70 elders changed the course of God's word and replaced it with man made rules. What do you read: the new Babylonian Talmud or the Old Testament?

Comment: if you are going to minus a question why not comment?

Comment: I don't think any of us even know where to begin.  Your rambling prose is extremely difficult to parse, and your shaky conception of Jewish history diverges greatly from both Jewish and academic narratives.

Comment: not really have you spent time studying the encyclopedias? The history is old and beautiful. It is a big uestion and prob requires even more extractions from the encyclopedia but surely you know if we are reading the old testament unmodified by man written by god or the pharisees adaptation of gods word. it is even said when moses received the 10 commandments the scribes of pharisees who where at the bottom of the mountain "supposedly" received a more in depth teaching then moses received.

Comment: Not sure how my views on history can be different from jewish and academic narratives if this history and teaching is written down in some of the oldest jewsish books. i mean did they write these books so we could do what ignore them and write a different history?

Comment: If you won't acknowledge the authority of the works of law, it is hard to give an answer that you will accept. I am sure that someone will be happy to explain to you how these laws are authoritative, though.

Comment: laws and translations of law is irrelevant IF the books we are reading from are not the words of god anymore. surely if it is written that things have changed then we need to know, why read words that are not of god but men its as bad as following the word of a gentile, and if it is written in our oldest books that something is not right anymore surely we should re explore this fact. we lead the world then we must also lead it responsibility and with the true word of god. I do feel that these old books have something to say and in some cases it feels like they are telling truth.

Comment: david, I've never heard of the _Judaic Encyclopedia_ and don't know anything about the quality of the _Universal Jewish Encyclopedia_; but the _Jewish Encyclopedia_ is respected. I'm curious where in the latter you found the ideas you seem to be paraphrasing in your question. What's the article title, please? I'm curious to [look it up](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/). I wonder, in fact, whether you misinterpreted something.

Comment: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12087-pharisees is a start on some of the history of the pharisees gaining power and CHANGE occurring. Im sure you have read the talmud which is an even more interesting read, really quite concerning it just doesnt seem write to me. our people our histroy is important and its the peoples responsiblity to make sure where not being misguided. i do not wish to question things but when it is written that things have changed then i cant help but ask how and for what reason, surely if god gave a word then it would be logical and holy

Comment: enough to withstand time and any situation if pure and holy, there would be no need for change. why would god as powerful creator say something that is only relevant for a couple o hundred years then leave it up to us to manipulate to fit our needs. it is not a choice to have responsibility nor is responsibility something to be disregarded as choice. History shows the clear movement of what i see ass is influences from other cultures entering Judaism and in order for our new desires to be met the scripts where

Comment: changed in order to allow for Babylonian ways to continue and continue in a justified manner. no man has the power or right to change the word of god.

Comment: @david Actually, we Jews believe that man does have control of the system of Halacha and can declare the Halacha independent of God, as it says in the Bible: לא בשמים היא = [Torah] is not in Heaven.

Comment: @DoubleAA, well, yes, but he's right we can't "change the word of [G]od" (or at least he's right depending on how you interpret that claim).

Comment: @msh210 It seems to me that he was using it to imply that Chazal could not interpret the Torah as they saw fit and we need to do exactly what Moshe did. I agree there is a specific process to follow etc.

Comment: It seems to me that our history shows us that we should lead the world yes, which we have achieved but i think there has become moral issues of this leadership. i dont not believe it was meant for us alone to be held highly but to bring true justice (not money making systems of prejudice law systems or banking systems), nor should we promote the usage of bad media or war. think our purpose has been clouded in a man made desires, and maybe not the majority but certainly the powerful. I believe the people

Comment: should stand up against immoral ways and not just ignore them. We do live in a time where people must question the past and preseant and see where it is leading.

Comment: @david, it's hard for me to tell what you're asking and it feels like you might be asking one or several big, sweeping questions.  Can you ask this as one or more more-tightly-focused questions?  I think we'll be able to help you more if you can do that.

Comment: re Khazars, there was a popular school of thought, particularly during the 1970s, which held that "70%" or so (as you put it) of the current Jewish population derived from the Khazars (and you can find all sorts of tendentious books such as "The Thirteenth Tribe"). More recent genetic research has largely disproved these theories. In any case, it's totally irrelevant where the genetic stock of the Jews derives from - the distinctive thing about am Yisrael is it is a covenant community connected with G-d and Torah (eg, Tanakh and Talmud), and this is the framework of historical continuity

Answer (score 2):

Both: we read [the Babylonian Talmud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_Talmud) *and* [Tanach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanakh).

Comment: Thank you Sir. Do you think it is ok to read the the Babylonian Talmud? i have read it and it upsets me if im honest, makes me cry, i cant understand that the word of god would be like this.

Comment: *I* think it's okay. I suppose if it makes you cry you should avoid it. Unless you're in the mood for a good cry.

Comment: but somethings just seem so... dont even want to say it.... wrong???

Comment: even for you to say "i think it okay"??? to me that would be blasphemy??? for something as important as a book telling us the holiest of holiest of ways to live to be just okay, says a lot to me.

Comment: thought it was intresting (not that i read from wiki but u did post the link) the wikipedia says The Babylonian Talmud records the opinions of the rabbis of Israel as well as of those of Babylonia, while the Jerusalem Talmud only seldom cites the Babylonian rabbis. The Babylonian version also contains the opinions of more generations because of its later date of completion. For both these reasons it is regarded as a more comprehensive collection of the opinions

Comment: available. On the other hand, because of the centuries of redaction between the composition of the Jerusalem and the Babylonian Talmud, the opinions of early amoraim might be closer to their original form in the Jerusalem Talmud.

Comment: I was told earlier to not answer a question based on opinion, am i reading this right? "The Babylonian Talmud records the opinions of the rabbis of Israel as well as of those of Babylonia" opinion??? where living off opinions of men?

Comment: If you read the history of Babylon and there ways of life you will understand more clearly why the Babylonian Talmud reads the way it does.

Comment: Re "for something as important as a book telling us the holiest of holiest of ways to live to be just okay, says a lot to me": I didn't say the book's merely okay. I said reading it's okay, because you'd asked "Do you think it is ok". I didn't mean reading it's *merely* okay, either, but was replying to your question.

Comment: I can understand that. sorry to be so questioning there is a lot going on through the influences of books and those outputs are not right and would like to see people address these issues rather then hide in the text for answers. We no what wrong is, the process of bringing unhappiness to yourself, animals or another human being. no exceptions and it is perfectly attainable to do so on a daily basis locally and globally. but u can only lead by example.

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam recommends spending one third of one's available time for study reading Tanach, and the other two thirds reading Talmud (Hilchot Talmud Torah 1:11).

Rabbeinu Tam on the other hand (Tosfot Sanhedrin 24a sv Belulah), feels that by reading Talmud, one also is credited with reading Tanach because the Talmud is full of citations from Tanach.

Comment: Rambam only applies to the early stages of one's learning. Shelah and others say that Rabbenu Tam only refers to the daily learning requirements, but that distinct from this, one should study scripture.

Comment: @mevaqesh Any answer to this question is going to be a simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Jews read many sources.

**Publicly fixed readings**

We read the Torah publicly three times weekly.  The entire Torah is thus read entirely each year - from "In the Beginning" until the end of Deuteronomy.

We read another section of the Bible weekly (usually something from one of the later prophets, but there's a [set order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah#List_of_Haftarot%20set%20order)).  On Purim, we read the Book of Esther twice.  On Tisha B'Av, we read Lamentations twice.  On Passover and some before Shabbat, we read Song of Songs (Canticles).  On Shavuot, we read Ruth. On Sukkot, we read Ecclesiastes.

We read many psalms in whole on a regular basis - daily, weekly, monthly - as part of our fixed prayers, or as part of various ceremonies (funerals, rememberances, etc.).  Most of our prayers are also dotted with lines from or references to Psalms and Proverbs, as well as Torah and other parts of the Bible.

We also publicly read excerpts from the Talmud and from the Mishnah on a regular basis.  Some congregations also read excerpts from the Zohar, a later mystical understanding of the Torah.

**Non-fixed readings**

In other settings, Jews read many sources.  Some occupy their days learning Talmud.  Others read from the Bible.  Others learn Zohar.  Some learn midrash - stories.  Others learn commentaries of the more famous rabbis or they learn laws as they've evolved over time.  Many Jews who consider themselves learned can read from the Torah and Prophets directly using the [Masoretic text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_text) which has remained consistent since at least the 10th century (the exact letters of the Five Books themselves have been around much longer - there have been minor changes to the later books).

Most people consider all of the above to be part of the rich corpus of Jewish thought.  The Torah, the rest of the Bible, Mishnah, both Talmuds, works of law, like the Shulchan Aruch, writings of rabbis like Rashi and Ramban, the mystical Zohar, the intellectual works of moderns and the moral works like The Path of the Just.  All of these are just a portion of the influences of modern Jewish thought.

**Apocrypha and miscellany**

As for the Khazars and the Pharisees, I think you need to read a bit more on that.  It seems you have confused a number of parts of history - some of which may very well be apocryphal.  I'd suggest perhaps taking a class on Jewish history if that interests you.  [Florence Melton Adult Mini-School](http://www.fmams.org.il/) is an incredible two-year program that might help you answer a lot of the questions you've been asking about Jewish thought, Jewish ethics, and Jewish history.  Good luck in your quest.